# Standard UI for adding entries to a table

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I have a table with items in it and I want a way to add items to that list when the user clicks on a `UIBarButtonItem` by filling in two fields with a string and an integer. Originally I tried a `UIAlertView` with text fields on it, which turned out to be a no-no.

Would you create a table view with buttons, and then have those buttons move the user to a different view with a text field, like adding a new alarm in the "Clock" app, or would you create cells with text fields, like when adding a new contact in the "Contacts" app?

EDIT: I've created a separate view that pops up when you click the button. I've added a table view with 2 entries (Accessory view) and I would like these buttons to be textfields. Is there a way to do this? Am I doing it the right way? Should I be doing it another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would add a new item by having an add button on your navigation bar that when touched, presents a modal view with a form for the user to fill in.

But there is no single correct way of adding items. It will depend very much on the purpose and style of your app. I suggest reading the Human Interface Guidelines - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/MobileHIG.pdf - provided by Apple and also look at other apps for examples of how to do it.

Comment: I've added some additional details, please have a look.

Comment: That's right, but you should add the textfields to the cell's contentView. Check out http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a table with items in it and I want a way to add items to that list when the user clicks on a `UIBarButtonItem` by filling in two fields with a string and an integer. Originally I tried a `UIAlertView` with text fields on it, which turned out to be a no-no.

Would you create a table view with buttons, and then have those buttons move the user to a different view with a text field, like adding a new alarm in the "Clock" app, or would you create cells with text fields, like when adding a new contact in the "Contacts" app?

Can you explain more clearly  What you exactly needed,

My point of view is if you like to create one new alarm or contact, create a page to add and update where you like to see that requisite.Best and clear explained way for the user

Comment: I have added some more details, please have a look.

Comment: while cliking edit u adding the content in the tableview right?

Comment: Well it's a + button, but it doesn't make much of a difference. The view that I've added is basically supposed to accept 2 inputs from the user. However I'm not quite certain if this can be done in a tableview. Simply dragging textfields and labels onto a blank UIView doesn't look very nice.

Comment: use the bottom of the page as the new input,make it hidden.if the user need to add he will click the add button(place it in the top right), then if the input given from the user just add in the tableview